# How do you programmatically apply a css class to an asp.net control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I'm wondering how I can apply a CSS class to an ASP.NET Control (TextBox in this case) through the backend in C#. For example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="firstName" CssClass="input left" runat="server" Text="First Name" />
```

I'd like to add another class to the element "selected" if a value is true that I test for on the backend.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="firstName" CssClass="input left selected" runat="server" Text="First Name" />
```

What is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: from this `I'd like to add another class to the element "selected" if a value is true that I test for on the backend.` it seems you wanted to check for a expression that evaluates to true/false . what do you want to test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
 firstName.CssClass = "input left selected".
```

If you want to append to any existing class names, do this:

```
firstName.CssClass += " selected";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a string property of [WebControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx):

```
firstName.CssClass += " selected";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(yourCondition) {
    var css = "myClass";
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.CssClass))
        element.CssClass = css;
    else
        element.CssClass += " " + css;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do that in the normal way something like below:

```
      if (value.Equals(true))
       {
            firstName.CSSClass = "input left selected";
       }
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an entry in the ViewDataDictionary for the class.

The backend would look something like

```
ViewData["selectedclass"] = <conditionalstatement> ? "selected" : "";
```

And the view would be

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="firstName" CssClass="input left <%= ViewData["selectedclass"]%>" runat="server" Text="First Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement adding cssClass like

```
firstName.CssClass = "input left selected";
```

Or

make onClick event for textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="firstName" CssClass="input left" runat="server" Text="First Name" OnClick="firstName_Click"  />
```

Then in code-behind:

```
void firstName_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MyTextBox.CssClass = "input left selected";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use attribute of ui controls

```
firstName.Attributes["css"]="Your Class Name";
```