# assign css class to a panel from code asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to assign a css class  for a panel. because i need to display data from the data base without using grid view .so that i can display all the data in dynamic panels..

without using grid view is their any other way to do it,

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                     Panel k=new Panel();
                //(col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4) css call wcich i need to add for this panel
                // add lable
                Panel2.Conrols.add(k);  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `CssClass` property of the `Panel` to set the class, as shown in this answer [How do you programmatically apply a css class to an asp.net control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571801/how-do-you-programmatically-apply-a-css-class-to-an-asp-net-control)

*You can just do this:*

```
 firstName.CssClass = "input left selected".
```

*If you want to append to any existing class names, do this:*

```
 firstName.CssClass += " selected";
```